# matlab - Tone generator

Tags: matlab, dtmf

I am trying to generate via matlab the DTMF tone using a default function, for the button 5 let say, with no luck at all. The code is:

```
button5= sin(0.5906*n)+sin(1.0247*n); This line of code is obligated. 

n=linspace (-1, 1, 1000);
Fs = 8192;
button5 = sin(0.5906*n)+sin(1.0247*n);
sound(button5, Fs);
```

Could you please advise regarding?

To explain better:

1. This is the table matrix for the button and the general code for the button 5 is: d5[n] = sin(0.5906n) + sin(1.0247n)

[image]

Comment: Why do you say that line is wrong?

Comment: What frequently do you aim for? It seems to generate a tone by far below the human range.

Comment: @Daniel The frequency is fine, in this case the desired is 770Hz and 1336Hz. I also test it in Matlab and it sounds.

Comment: @dubafek: Definitely not, it is below 1 Hz. Just plot the signal to see it is less than one cycle.

Comment: @Daniel Actually the problem is that it's less than one cycle, but that's nothing related with the frecuency, you have to consider the sample rate. The problem is the time, the `n` vector must be longer.

Comment: There is another issue with your code. Simplifying to one frequency, with 1000 samples a frequency of 1336 the sampled signal should contain 163 periods. My problem answering that question is I have no idea how DTMF works and I have no idea where the first line comes from.

Comment: Still no tone sound. The first line is obligatory. Which should be the rest of code to hear it?

Comment: What is omega? There must be some explanation! Small omega is typically used for the angular frequency but I never saw capital omega in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying some combinations of the numbers, I realized Ω is the precomputed `2*pi*f/FS` where f is the frequency.

Here is a version just rewriting the answer from dubafek substituting some variables:

```
f=[770 1336];
Fs = 8192;
n = [0:10000];
omega=2.*pi.*f./Fs;
button5 = sin(omega(1)*n)+sin(omega(2)*n);
button5=button5/max(button5(:));
sound(button5, Fs);
```

Which, replacing omega with constants leads to:

```
Fs = 8192;
n = [0:10000];
button5 = sin(0.5906*n)+sin(1.0247*n);
button5=button5/max(button5(:));
sound(button5, Fs);
```

The minor differences in the result are because the constant omega in the second case is rounded to four digits. Now having the solution I realize it was only a simple information missing in your question, `n` is a vector containing the natural  numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused about your code cause I prefer to state it another way. As @Daniel says, the problem is using the 1000 samples to normalize frequency.

This code should work:

```
Fs = 8192;
n = [0:10000];
t = n/Fs;
button5 = sin(2*pi*770*t)+sin(2*pi*1336*t);
sound(button5/max(button5) ,Fs)
```

Comment: You forgot to normalize. Using `sound(button5/max(button5),Fs)` I can not notice any difference to a [reference signal](http://www.matthis.thorade.de/mfv/index.php?nummer=5) (choose a number and  hit "Wählen")

Comment: You need to add the first line of my init post. It is obligatory. This code works but normaly I have not the frequncies. I have the Ω.

Comment: He does not need to do anything for you. You may ask, but don't demand anything! He did a good job somehow making a sense of your unclear and incomplete question and provided a good answer. Explain the math behind those magic numbers and explain what omega is and you might receive an improved answer.

Comment: Kindly again. I just modified the initial post as mentioned @Daniel for further explanation. My problem is that I am pretty obligated to use in my code the above edited table matrix instead the 770 and the 1336 and the 2*pi*f respectively that they are more clear to all of us. Those values in the matrix table seem to me magic as well, however I have the restriction to use them. So for 1000 samples and for the function d5[n] = sin(0.5906n) + sin(1.0247n) for button 5 what should be the sequence of code commands?